# Converting nested JSON into a flattened DataFrame

Tags: python, json, dictionary, nested, json-normalize

I have a data load in nested json format and I want to get a nested dataframe

```
{
    "page_count": 21,
    "page_number": 1,
    "page_size": 300,
    "total_records": 6128,
    "registrants": [
        {
            "id": "23lnTNqyQ3qkthfghjgkk",
            "first_name": "HUGO",
            "last_name": "MACHA   ILLEN",
            "email": "hugreb@hotmail.com",
            "address": "",
            "city": "",
            "country": "",
            "zip": "",
            "state": "",
            "phone": "",
            "industry": "",
            "org": "",
            "job_title": "",
            "purchasing_time_frame": "",
            "role_in_purchase_process": "",
            "no_of_employees": "",
            "comments": "",
            "custom_questions": [
                {
                    "title": "Departamento/ Región",
                    "value": ""
                },
                {
                    "title": "Género",
                    "value": "Masculino"
                },
                {
                    "title": "Edad",
                    "value": "De 35 a 55 años"
                },
                {
                    "title": "Nivel de estudio",
                    "value": "Técnico / Superior"
                },
                {
                    "title": "¿Eres cliente de una entidad financiera?",
                    "value": "Si"
                },
                {
                    "title": "¿Tiene una empresa?",
                    "value": "Si"
                }
```

I use this funtion:
pat is the file json

```
df = pd.json_normalize(json.loads(pat.explode("custom_questions").to_json(orient="records")))
```

but it didn't work for the output i wanted.

I want get someone like this:

[image]

I want the value of the "titles", that is, the keys" to be displayed as the column headers and the value of "value" as the data. As well as the image that is attached

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Your json is invalid. Please make sure you type it correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use json_normalize:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(your_json['registrants']).explode('custom_questions').reset_index(drop=True)
df=df.join(pd.json_normalize(df.pop('custom_questions')))

#convert rows to columns. Set index first 17 columns. We will not use theese.
df=df.set_index(df.columns[0:17].to_list())
dfx=df.pivot_table(values='value',columns='title',aggfunc=list).apply(pd.Series.explode).reset_index(drop=True)

#we have duplicate rows. Drop them
df=df.reset_index().drop(['value','title'],axis=1).drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True)
df=df.join(dfx)
'''
|    | id                    | first_name   | last_name     | email              | address   | city   | country   | zip   | state   | phone   | industry   | org   | job_title   | purchasing_time_frame   | role_in_purchase_process   | no_of_employees   | comments   | Departamento/ Región   | Edad            | Género    | Nivel de estudio   | ¿Eres cliente de una entidad financiera?   | ¿Tiene una empresa?   |
|---:|:----------------------|:-------------|:--------------|:-------------------|:----------|:-------|:----------|:------|:--------|:--------|:-----------|:------|:------------|:------------------------|:---------------------------|:------------------|:-----------|:-----------------------|:----------------|:----------|:-------------------|:-------------------------------------------|:----------------------|
|  0 | 23lnTNqyQ3qkthfghjgkk | HUGO         | MACHA   ILLEN | hugreb@hotmail.com |           |        |           |       |         |         |            |       |             |                         |                            |                   |            |                        | De 35 a 55 años | Masculino | Técnico / Superior | Si                                         | Si                    |

'''
```

Comment: if the output comes out like yours. But I want the fields that are inside "title", department/region, gender, age, etc. to appear as column headers and the "value" below each one as rows as appropriate.

Comment: okey, i edited the answer. Can you check it ?

Comment: thanks a lot!!! It came out as required.